# Connect two moving components (car&trailer)

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

I'm making the first game using flutter and flame. Does anyone have an idea how to connect two or more components so that one follows the other. Example: a car (one component) is towing a trailer (second component). The car turns and the trailer turns behind it. Can it be done with flutter and flame

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this out of the box in pure Flame. You would have to add `flame_forge2d` and create `BodyComponent`s and put a `Joint` between the two bodies.

If you don't want to use Forge2D you can add both the car and the trailer to a common `PositionComponent` parent which you can move and then both of the components would move, but you would have to handle the angles manually so that it looks correct.